# Atimaharathi class of warrior: Was Parshurama one of the Atimaharathi?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, parashurama, war, indrajit

As per [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharathi_(warrior)) link, Parshurama belonged to the Atimaharathi class of warrior, the only other being Meghanaada. But some other links like [this](http://bhakti4mukti.blogspot.in/2015/08/7-levels-of-warrior-excellence-as-per.html) mentioned Parshurama as Maharathi.

Is there any relevant text mentioned in any of our Epics which clarify this ambiguity.

Thanks!